# Routerlink doesnt work with SVG's in Angular2

Tags: angular, svg, angular2-routing

I changed my toolbar from glyphicons in Bootstrap to custom SVG's. I referenced the SVG's externally via an  because i need to style them in one .css file. My html component looks like this:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" [routerLink]="['editor/text-properties']">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/svg/cv_text.svg" class="svg"></object>  
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" [routerLink]="['editor/image-properties']">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="assets/svg/cv_image.svg" class="svg"></object>  
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" [routerLink]="['editor/background-properties']">
    <object type="image" data="assets/svg/cv_photo.svg" class="svg"></object>  
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" [routerLink]="['editor/background-properties']">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-photo svg"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

As you can see, the last button works. The first three dont. The last one is how i had it at first. Here is the router typescript file:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { EditorTextPropertiesComponent } from "./editor/editor-properties/editor-text-properties/editor-text-properties.component";
import { EditorImagePropertiesComponent } from "./editor/editor-properties/editor-image-properties/editor-image-properties.component";
import { EditorBackgroundPropertiesComponent } from "./editor/editor-properties/editor-background-properties/editor-background-properties.component";

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'editor/text-properties', component: EditorTextPropertiesComponent },
    { path: 'editor/image-properties', component: EditorImagePropertiesComponent },
    { path: 'editor/background-properties', component: EditorBackgroundPropertiesComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

But there shouldnt be any errors here because my old buttons still works fine. I do get a error in my console from uBlock Origin, but when i open it in incognito window the error is gone and it still doesn't work so it couldn't be that. Here is the error:

```
Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg/cv_image.svg
    at chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79
chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79 Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg/cv_zoom_out.svg
    at chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79
chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79 Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg/cv_zoom_in.svg
    at chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79
chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79 Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg/cv_text.svg
    at chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79
chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79 Uncaught Error: uBlock Origin: aborting content scripts for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg/cv_photo.svg
    at chrome-extension://cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/js/contentscript.js:79
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: So i saw that if i click on the border my button it does work. So my svg  element is in front of the working routerlink.

EDIT2: Knowing that the border works, i figured that the underlying div worked, so i added "pointer-events: none;" to the  element. This worked! Now it clicks through the  element.

Comment: It comes from your uBlock extension

Comment: So then it would work in incognito mode? Where all plugins are disabled. But it still doesnt work, so it has to be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my answer in the question also:

So i saw that if i click on the border my button it does work. So my svg element is in front of the working routerlink.

Knowing that the border works, i figured that the underlying div worked, so i added "pointer-events: none;" to the element. This worked! Now it clicks through the element.